# Understanding grep -e '^>' command

Tags: grep

I don't understand this command:

```
grep -e '^>'
```

Not sure what any of it means after grep. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the command `grep --help` you can notice the **-e** option which is used for specifying a pattern or regex . You can also use **-E** for using extended regular expressions.
The character `^` means that the string must start with the specified character, in this case `^>` means that the string must start with a `>` character.
For example, if you type the next command:

`grep -e "^>" <(echo -e "Foo\n>Fuzz\nLinux\n>Unix")`

The output will be:

> >Fuzz

> >Unix

For this topics, I would recommend you read and learn about regex, here are some sites can visit:

[Linux Regular Expressions](https://www.guru99.com/linux-regular-expressions.html)

[Linux regex](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-on-linux/)

Comment: A good site to test and learn regular expressions is [regex101](https://regex101.com/). It shows you an explanation of every part of the expression and helps you to find errors fast.

Comment: @mashuptwice I didn't know about that site! It's so great.